# How to define string literal union types with JSDoc

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I'd like to write some JSDoc comments that will (possibly in future) enable VS Code to be able to use this information.  I've looked at the JSDoc examples and haven't found one that covers my specific use case (see code below).  I'll explain this further below the snippet.

```
/**
 * N: Not Started
 * P: In Progress
 * D: Done
 * A: Accepted
 * R: Released
 */
export type Status = "N" | "P" | "D" | "A" | "R";
```

What I was hoping for is to define a mapping for each of the single character strings to the description.  VS Code could show much better intellisense data if JS Doc provided a good way to define the mapping.  For example, if I see "N" in the list of possible values for a variable that's defined with the Status type, I'd like VS Code to be able to show "Not Started" next to that.  Is this possible with JS Doc?  NOTE: I'm not asking how to do this with VS Code because I think this is a chicken and egg problem- JS Doc will first need to support it before VS Code can do anything with it.  So I'd first like to see what the "correct" way of doing this is using JSDoc.

Comment: Is there a reason you can not use enum?

Comment: Looking for exactly this let me know if you find a solution @Kevin

Comment: @im_baby string values are a purer solution when using Javascript/TypeScript.  There's certain attributes of enums that make them less compatible with strings so they're not quite interchangeable.  The official docs here make this obvious: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-runtime